# Devise not redirecting when user destroy session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I can't get Devise to refresh the page when user signing out. Session is being destroyed but I need to refresh the page in order to see the user logged out. I've tried setting turbolinks to false, and using remote: true, with no luck. Any ideas?

**View**

```
<li><%= link_to "Salir", destroy_user_session_path(current_user), class: "dropdown-item", :method => 'delete'   %></li>
```

**Application Controller**

```
 def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
   request.referrer
  end
```

**Routes**

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
```

**Logs**

```
Started DELETE "/users/sign_out.91" for ::1 at 2021-05-16 14:22:54 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as 
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"VysuqONMdfsdfxA3cwH3UGliXGpjHVpE+Pxkk1eT7++S3fOQt5wyIJfuS90QrEVOMNxtYihSxQ/MMInkyypdeuC78Jw=="}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 91], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/activerecord-5.2.4.4/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Completed 204 No Content in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Comment: Have you tried another path besides `request.referrer`?

Comment: Are you sure the method `after_sign_out_path_for` is being called or not.

Comment: @dbugger yes, with no luck

Comment: @HirenBhalani I don't think it's being called, it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the link with

```
<li><%= link_to "Salir", destroy_user_session_path, class: "dropdown-item", :method => 'delete'   %></li>
```

Comment: Lol it was that simple. Worked! Thank you!